# Preview is not changing in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, preview

I explicitely specified device name in preview provider but it is not changing the device in preview editor.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone 11"))
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe try stringLiteral: ?

Comment: no luck :( .....

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the iPhone 11 simulator into your project? If it's not available in the device selection, it won't display by just setting the device in code. You need to have the simulator device installed as well.